# General Function to read from query string c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create general function that read from query string and then cast the value to its proper type. for example :
say URL: www.myWeb.com?intParm=111&strParam=hi There&guidParam=0DAE20CD-383B-41F8-B2A5-6231CE5012F0

First try:

```
   public object GetPage_Param(string _ParamName, object _Default)
    {
        object Value = null;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[_ParamName] != null)
            Value = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.GetValues(_ParamName)[0]);

        if (Value != null)
            Value = (_Default == null) ? string.Empty : _Default;
        if (Value is int)
            return System.Convert.ToInt32(Value);
        else if (Value is Int64)
            return System.Convert.ToInt64(Value);
        else if (Value is double)
            return System.Convert.ToDouble(Value);
        else if (Value is float)
            return System.Convert.ToSingle(Value);
        else if (Value is decimal)
            return System.Convert.ToDecimal(Value);
        else if(Value is Guid)
            return Guid.Parse(Value.ToString());
        else
            return Value;
    }
```

I still need to cast  i.e. Guid varGuid = GetPage_Param("guidParam", Guid.Empty); <-- this will give error since I need to parse the object to guid like varGuid = Guid.parse(GetPage_Param("guidParam", Guid.Empty));

Second try:

```
    public T GetPage_Param<T>(string _ParamName, T _Default)
    {
        object Value = null;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[_ParamName] != null)
            Value = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.GetValues(_ParamName)[0]);

        if (Value == null)
            Value = (_Default == null) ? string.Empty : _Default;

        return (T)Value;
    }
```

I believe this is not the right way ( :( error every ware) … any help, link, new idea Thanks :)

Kindly note I'm using asp.net webforms and framework 4.7.2

Comment: Is there any specific reason you don't let the framework parse your parameters?

Comment: checking for value and give default value … i'm open for any suggestion, help :)

Comment: If you define your parameters in your controller methods you can give them default values: `public void DoSomething(int? parm1, long parm2 = 0)`

Comment: sorry, I forget to tell that i'm using webforms :( not MVC or web api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QueryString` property of the `Request` object is a `NameValueCollection` - that's a collection of key value pairs where both the key and the value are strings.

This means that the `Value is int` in your code will always return false (and in fact, any other type that is not `string`).

What you can do is use `TryParse` instead:

```
if(int.TryParse(Value, out var value)) return value;
if(double.TryParse(Value, out var value)) return value;
```

and so on - however, this is also not a very good option since you might get false positives - some strings might be parseable as different types so you should be very careful about what you do if you decide to do this.

The best course of action is to decide in advance what data type you are willing to accept as every specific query string parameter and if convert them individually.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, I thing its a good idea and its working … inspired by your last two paragraphs … I begin to think about overload function to handle each datatype separately .